# Angular - How to merge these two observables with ngrx some magics?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, store, rxjs-observables

I have 2 observables. One returns an event and the other boolean. I want to create a new observable that returns the boolean or event while the value in the store is true. Here is the code. This obs1 should wait until the obs2 returns true.

```
const obs1 = fromEvent(window,'beforeunload')
const obs2 = this.store.select(aBooleanObservable)

const result: Observable<boolean>= ???
```

senario 1 = Event fired, value in the store true => result true 
senario 2 = Event fired, value in the store false => result noting emit until the value is chaneged to true

Comment: I guess you will have to do some work in this case but I think you can try `concat` and `takeuntil`

Answer (score 2):

```
const obs1 = fromEvent(window,'beforeunload')
const obs2 = this.store.select(aBooleanObservable)

const result: Observable<boolean>=  combineLatest(obs1, obs2).pipe(
filter((event, obvBoolean) => event && obvBoolean));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work, the following answer assumes obs1 only triggers once.  you could try

```html
const obs1 = fromEvent(window,'beforeunload')
const obs2 = this.store.select(aBooleanObservable)

const result: Observable<boolean>=  obs1
 .pipe(
   switchMap(()=> obs2 ),
   filter((aBooleanObservableRes)=>aBooleanObservableRes)
  
 )
```

Your result will only be returned when obs2 has a "true" boolean value.